# NET8 MAUI app on iOS or macCatalyst: Unable to create package spec for project

Tags: ios, maui, .net-8.0

I'm creating an app with `MAUI` and `NET8`. From my Windows laptop, I can't run the application via a `iOS` Simulator because it can't find a compatible device. Plus, I get this error

> A bundle identifier is required. Either add an 'ApplicationId' property in the project file, or add a 'CFBundleIdentifier' entry in the project's Info.plist file.

but if I open the `Info.plist`

[image]

If I try to run the same application on my iMAC with Visual Studio for Mac, I get this error

> Getting restore information for project /Users/enrico/Projects/LIUApp/LanguageInUse/LanguageInUse.csproj
>
> /usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk/7.0.310/Sdks/Microsoft.NET.Sdk/targets/Microsoft.NET.TargetFrameworkInference.targets(112,5) : error NETSDK1139: The target platform identifier ios was not recognized.
>
> Unable to create package spec for project. '/Users/enrico/Projects/LIUApp/LanguageInUse/LanguageInUse.csproj'

When I open the project, Visual Studio for Mac is installing the workload but definetely it is not working at the end.

How can I try my application in a iOS Simulator?

### Update

This is the screenshot in Visual Studio for Mac

[image]

[image]

Comment: *If I try to run the same application on my iMAC with Visual Studio for Mac, I get this error*  Do you mean that even if you create the same project on VS for Mac, it still won't run properly and will report an error?

Comment: Yes correct. I added the screenshot now

Comment: If so, the problem is related to the project. Try to use .net7 instead of .net8 ?